# GeoCoding API OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I have a website which for the last 3 years has been using the Google GeoCoding API from my server.  Starting this last week, the API was failing with a error 620 on the v2 API.  While my site is not high traffic I thought perhaps there was a defect causing me to hit the anonymous threshold or something was getting hammered by a site crawler, or someone else in the shared hosting environment was causing the threshold to be met.

I switched the API call to another server and used as a proxy and I was back in business again.  The next day it happened again.  I noticed that the API console document stated that I could run V3 API with a key and gain visibility through the console of how many requests I was making in 24 hours.

I upgraded to V3 Maps API for server-side geocoding and found that I would always get a REQUEST_DENIED when I included the key.  If I did not include the key, it works but after a day or so it stops working with an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and then starts the next day. Note, that I am setting the required "sensor" param.

So, I can only assume that I hit the threshold of 2,500 a day based on google behavior, but my site traffic reports do not support that.  I can't confirm with the google key approach because it doesn't work.  Any support/ideas would be helpful.  I have been using the API successfully for three years and this just cropped up within the last 6 days.

Help!!

Rob

Comment: I have a similar problem... did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: I also have a similar issue because I need the urls to be indexed and do not want to block the crawlers. Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Delay for 500 millisecond to get your results.

Here is a sample code.

```
loc = GeocodeAddresses(fullAddress);
                        if (loc != null)
                        {
                            lat = double.Parse(loc.lat);
                            lng = double.Parse(loc.lng);

                            int milliseconds = 500;
                            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
```

This works great for me.